# How i Do OnClick Button From VB.NET to Website Button

Tags: vb.net, button, onclick

I need Help about the on click button my website url is https://visualstudiocodes.blogspot.com/ i have one button there. i want to click from vb.net button to my website button.How i can to it i have use the below coding but it not working ...

```
 "https://visualstudiocodes.blogspot.com/".Document.GetElementById("mybutton").InvokeMember("click")
```

Comment: Is this in a Windows Form?

Comment: yes this is window form i have a button i want when i click the vb.net form button then my website button will clicked.

Comment: Do you have a [WebView2 Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) on the form?

Comment: yes i have control

Comment: YOU DONT GIVE THE ANSER

Comment: I haven't used a WebView2 control, but it looks like you would need to use the [CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.executescriptasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1150.38#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2-executescriptasync(system-string)) to run some JavaScript to click the button. Also, you might need to wait for the...

Comment: ... [WebView2.NavigationCompleted Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.navigationcompleted?source=recommendations&view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1418.22) to be raised before trying to access elements on the page.